# How to change the active class in a navbar in react

Tags: reactjs

**Problem:**

I am creating a React web application. In there I have created a side navbar like this.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

import imagine from "../../../assets/img/sidebar-2.jpg";

class Sidebar extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      activeTabClassName: "tab1"
    };
  }

  // activeRoute(routeName) {
  //   return this.props.location.pathname.indexOf(routeName) > -1 ? "active" : "";
  // }

  updateDimensions() {
    this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    const sidebarBackground = {
      backgroundImage: "url(" + imagine + ")"
    };
    return (
      <div className="sidebar" data-image={imagine} id="sidebar">
        <div className="sidebar-background" style={sidebarBackground} />
        <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
          <div className="logo">
            <a href="/" className="simple-text">
              <img
                src="../../images/favicon.png"
                style={{ maxHeight: "50px" }}
              />
              Trafficfine
            </a>
          </div>
          <ul className="nav">
            <li className="nav-item active">
              <a className="nav-link" href="/admin/dashbord">
                <i className="fas fa-tachometer-alt" />
                <p>Dashboard</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" href="/admin/officers">
                <i className="fas fa-briefcase" />
                <p>Officers</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="nav-link" href="/admin/offences">
                <i className="fas fa-times-circle" />
                <p>Offences</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a className="nav-link" href="/admin/drivers">
                <i className="fas fa-bus-alt" />
                <p>Drivers</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

I want to change the active class dynamically when a user is clicking on the nav Item and add some styling to the active class. I saw some similar questions have been asked on the stack overflow and I tried those example. But through those, I was unable to achieve that. Can someone help me to solve my problem by modifying 
my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You already have your target class in `state`, you just need to add it like this

```
<div className={"sidebar " + this.state.activeTabClassName} data-image={imagine} id="sidebar">
```

And call `this.setState( {activeTabClassName: "newActiveClass"} )` when you want to change it.